# Como selecionar mais de um item em um Select Option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html5

Preciso escolher mais de uma option em um select. Por exemplo, poderia ter um checkbox dentro do select porem não sei como fazer, podem me ajudar?

```
<div class="col-md-3">
     <label style="color: red;">Filial</label >
     <select ng-model="modelcompraevenda.filial" 
             class="form-control" id="myDropdown" 
             style="z-index:0" ng-
             options="x.nomeFilial for x in 
             modelcompraevenda.listFiliais track by 
     x.idFilial">
     </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Dá-lhe o atributo `multiple`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-multiple

Comment: tem outra melhor opção?

Comment: Melhor em que aspeto? O que é que não funciona como queres?

Comment: em questão visual, não esta explicito que o usuario pode selecionar mais de um item e a cada click ele não ficar marcado qual esta ou não selecionado

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode criar um select normal com a tag multiple na frente, onde o usuário seleciona com ctrl as opções multiplas no seu select, quando passado por post, receberá algo como:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
<select name="opcoes" multiple>
  <option value="opcao1">opcao1</option>
  <option value="opcao2">opcao2</option>
  <option value="opcao3">opcao3</option>
  <option value="opcao4">opcao4</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

opcoes=opcao1&opcoes=opcao2&opcoes=opcao3

Depois você pode tratar com js, jquery, php ou a linguagem que está utilizando.

Uma outra solução bem legal é usar um plugin jquery, utilizei recentemente esse: http://loudev.com/ ele é bem legal e elegante.

Sobre o multi select, da uma olhada nessa documentação:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que tenha encontrado a solução que você descreveu:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option

São checkbox dentro do select.

**code:**

```js
var expanded = false;

function showCheckboxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 200px;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
}

#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}

#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
      <select>
        <option>Select an option</option>
      </select>
      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxes">
      <label for="one">
        <input type="checkbox" id="one" />First checkbox</label>
      <label for="two">
        <input type="checkbox" id="two" />Second checkbox</label>
      <label for="three">
        <input type="checkbox" id="three" />Third checkbox</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso apenas adicionando o atributo `multiple` no seu `select`.

```html
<select multiple name="lista">
  <option value="1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="2">Item 2</option>
</select>
```

Caso queira melhorar o visual e deixar mais sugestivo você pode por um mensagem para o usuário em uma `label` por exemplo e também melhorar o visual utilizando `css`.

Vou demonstrar abaixo como fica o `select multiple` utilizando o [Plugin jquery select2](https://select2.org) que eu acredito ser muito prático:

```js
$(".select2").select2();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="idSelect2">
    Clique para selecionar um ou mais alunos:
    </label>
</div>
<div>
  <select class="select2 form-control" id="idSelect2" multiple="" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
    <optgroup label="Ciência da computação">
      <option value="1">Herp</option>
      <option value="2">Derp</option>
      <option value="3">Caique</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Administracao">
      <option value="4">Larissa</option>
      <option value="5">Bruna</option>
      <option value="6">Natalia</option>
      <option value="7">Maria</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um script à mão (usando jQuery) que substitui um `<select>` de **múltipla escolha** por um *dropdown* com `checkbox` para cada opção.

**Como funciona:**

Adicionei 2 `div`s abaixo do `<select>` para receber o `dropdown`.

O script esconde o `<select>` e cria um *dropdown* nas `div`s baseado nas informações do `<select>`.

Quando um `checkbox` é marcado, o `<option>` correspondente do `<select>` oculto é selecionado, recebendo o atributo `selected="selected"`. Quando é desmarcado, o atributo é removido.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 el_select = $("select[name=lista]");
 el_select.hide();
 $.each(el_select.find("option"), function(){
  $("#novo_select_container ul").append(
  '<li><input type="checkbox" value="'+$(this).val()+'" />'+$(this).text()+'</li>'
  );
 });

 $("#novo_select input[type=checkbox]").on("click",function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
   $("select[name=lista] option[value="+$(this).val()+"]").attr("selected","selected");
  }else{
   $("select[name=lista] option[value="+$(this).val()+"]").removeAttr("selected");
  }
 });

 $("#novo_select li:not(:eq(0))").on("click",function(){
  $(this).find("input").trigger("click");
 });

 $("#novo_select_container li:eq(0)").on("click", function(){
  if($("#novo_select").hasClass("novo_select_fechado")){
   $("#novo_select").removeClass("novo_select_fechado").addClass("novo_select_aberto");
   $("#novo_select_container").css("height","auto");
  }else{
   $("#novo_select").removeClass("novo_select_aberto").addClass("novo_select_fechado");
   $("#novo_select_container").css("height","21px");
  }
 });

 $("#novo_select_container li input, #novo_select_container li").on("click", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
 });
 
 $(document).on('click',function(){
  if($("#novo_select").hasClass("novo_select_aberto")){
   $("#novo_select").removeClass("novo_select_aberto").addClass("novo_select_fechado");
   $("#novo_select_container").css("height","21px");
  }
 });
});
```

```css
#novo_select_container{
 position: relative;
 height: 21px;
 display: inline-block;
}

#novo_select{
 background: #ddd;
}

#novo_select li, #novo_select ul{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

#novo_select li{
 padding: 0 10px;
 line-height: 25px;
 cursor: default;
}

#novo_select li:first-child{
 background: url(https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/navigation/arrow_drop_down_grey_192x192.png) right no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
 padding-right: 25px;
}

.novo_select_aberto{
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}

.novo_select_fechado{
 position: absolute;
 clip: rect(0px 1000px 25px 0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple name="lista">
  <option value="1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="2">Item 2</option>
</select>
<div id="novo_select_container">
 <div id="novo_select" class="novo_select_fechado"><ul><li>Selecione...</li></ul></div>
</div>
```