# Selecionar varias opções no select

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tenho este `select`:

```
<div>
<label for="Indicar">Colaborador: </label>
<select class="form-control" name="Notas" id="Notas26">
      <option></option>
      <?php        
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM raddb.usuarios ORDER BY nome ASC";
         $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
         while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
            echo '<option value="'.$ln['id'].'">'.$ln['nome'].'</option>';
         }
      ?>        
</select>
</div>
```

Dentro do `select` vão aparecer diversos colaboradores. Quero ter a possibilidade de poder selecionar vários colaboradores.

Tentei seguir [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/245356/como-selecionar-mais-de-um-item-em-um-select-option), mas não consegui implementar.

Comment: É só colocar `multiple` no select.

Comment: @Sam , sim já coloquei. Estava a tentar usar o código da tua resposta, porque o multiple, cria uma caixa muito grande, mas resolvo com css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente adicionar o atributo `multiple` no seu `select`.
O atributo `multiple` é um atributo booleano que quando presente, especifica que várias opções podem ser selecionadas de uma só vez.

```
<div>
<label for="Indicar">Colaborador: </label>
<select class="form-control" name="notas[]" id="Notas26" multiple>
      <option></option>
      <?php        
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM raddb.usuarios ORDER BY nome ASC";
         $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
         while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
            echo '<option value="'.$ln['id'].'">'.$ln['nome'].'</option>';
         }
      ?>        
</select>
</div>
```

Para manipular os valores selecionados no `php`:

```
foreach ($_POST['notas'] as $nota)  
    print "Você selecionou $nota<br/>";
```